# Implement search bar using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a beginner React app and am not able to understand how to handle my state so that I can redirect to a search results page:

I have a main App component which uses React Router to deliver two components:

1) Landing (`/`) -- has an input and should take you to `/search` and show only those objects whose title match your input
2) Search (`/search`) -- either shows all objects if accessing the page directly or your filtered based upon your input

My question is: if I handle the state in the App component, it will cause the state to update and a rerender upon a user typing in the Landing input element, but how can I get it to go to /search with the updated state? The index route will keep getting hit since it's just a rerender and the user is still on the landing page.

I would like to handle this without redux as this will be a very small app.

Here is the code for my parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { shape, string } from "prop-types";

import Landing from "./Landing";
import Search from "./Search";
import { shows } from "../data.json";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: ""
    };
    this.updateSearchTermHandler = this.updateSearchTermHandler.bind(this);
  }

  updateSearchTermHandler(searchTerm) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              component={props => (
                <Landing
                  updateSearchTermHandler={this.updateSearchTermHandler}
                  searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
                  {...props}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/search"
              component={props => (
                <Search
                  updateSearchTermHandler={this.updateSearchTermHandler}
                  shows={shows}
                  {...props}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  match: shape({
    params: string.isRequired
  }).isRequired
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to instead use a `<Router>` with your own `history`. You could then call `history.replace('/search', { searchTerm: 'foo' })`

And then in your Landing component, you will have `this.props.history.location.state.searchTerm`

See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router for further details on creating history